# What happened to Bespin after the events of Empire?

Tags: star-wars

Presumably the Empire took it over, but did they shut it down? Did they continue to mine the valuable Tibanna gas, even though it was technically illegal? Was there a repossession auction? Did Lando, either himself or through rebel agents, attempt to reclaim or repurpose any equipment? What about the citizens who didn't escape?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Within the new [official canon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Canon) of *Star Wars* (e.g. The 11 feature films, *Clone Wars* TV series and movie, *Rebels* TV series) there's no further mention of Cloud City or its 5 million inhabitants beyond the end of *The Empire Strikes back*.

---

Elsewhere in the EU, there are extensive references including a visit from Jabba the Hutta's father (who [becomes Governor for a few hours](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Prince)), an [occupation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Jedi_Knight_II:_Jedi_Outcast) by Grand Admiral Thrawn's forces, recovery by Lando and a strike force and the city's eventual fall into ruin after (what else!) a [trade dispute](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Nest_II:_The_Unseen_Queen).

You can read a potted history [here](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cloud_City) on the Star Wars Wookieepedia website.

Comment: 6 feature films?

Comment: @Edlothiad - This needs a lot more updating. I'm sure there are numerous canon mentions of Bespin after ESB now

Comment: @Edlothiad *9* feature films? **Edit:** Oh wait... you probably mean *in* universe. *4* feature films? :)

Comment: @Lexible - Trilogy, prequel trilogy, reboot trilogy, Rogue One, Solo. I've mentioned the Clone Wars film in the subsequent part of the list.

Answer (score 1):

There's a canon mobile game called *Star Wars: Uprising*, which deals with the rebellion in the Anoat sector (including Bespin) after *Return of the Jedi*. Lobot lead a rebellion on Bespin which the Smuggler (the main character of the game) took part in.